# Does marriage exist in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, marriage

Has anyone ever been definitively married in Star Wars? Luke's adoptive parents certainly seemed like husband and wife, but did they ever actually refer to each other as such? Having now watched The Force Awakens several times, I can say there is no mention of a past or current marriage between the parents of Kylo Ren. Is there any evidence that marriage exists in that galaxy, far, far away?

I have heard mention of things called prequels. I don't know of those, but, if it's canon, I'll buy it.

**EDIT:** While answers to earlier questions also answer this question, the answers that have already been posted to this question answer it far more completely. It's not a duplicate; if I hadn't seen the prequels (I haven't), I wouldn't know to look for Anakin and Padme.

Thanks everyone, for the answers, feedback, and votes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Han and Leia still married?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113222/are-han-and-leia-still-married) The question isn't the same, but its answers will answer your question.

Comment: The prequels are better than *The Force Awakens*. They may not have the greatest dialogue, but at least they have an original plot.

Comment: Sadly, it's no longer canon, but in "Legends," there was even a ["Dark Book of Imperial Justice"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Book_of_Imperial_Justice) that was read during Imperial dark marriages. It showed up in a book about the wedding between a three-eyed successor to Palpatine and a droid copy of Leia with blaster eyes.

Comment: @sumelic ...and that's a crowning argument for the eradication of the old E.U.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who were the witnesses at the marriage of Padmé Amidala and Anakin Skywalker?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/who-were-the-witnesses-at-the-marriage-of-padm%c3%a9-amidala-and-anakin-skywalker)

Comment: Luke does shout for "Uncle Owen! Aunt Beru!" If they're not married, then one of them is Amidala's brother or sister and the other is the second child of "There-was-no-man Shmi"

Comment: @Null some people prefer well-executed art to original art.

Comment: @Null I enjoy the prequel trilogy for their plot and action sequences, but given that they are often poorly paced and acted I would have to say that The Force Awakens is generally better.

Comment: @RogueJedi, different questions with the same answers are still different questions. See: `2+2` and `2*2`.

Comment: @OrangeDog That *The Force Awakens* was well-executed is arguable. Either way, by re-using the plot from the OT it was a lazy use of the *Star Wars* brand to make money. It is harmful to the franchise since it is taking up space in canon that could have been used on more original stories (which could have also been well-executed).

Comment: Have you even seen  all the Star Wars movies?

Comment: No, I have not seen the prequels. I'll probably break down and watch them while waiting for Episode VIII.

Comment: @Jolenealaska If you have the time, watch IV, V prequels, VI. They become a perfectly timed, giant flashback instead of just a bunch of movies about an awkward kid.

Comment: @Null: If I were to present the remains of everything I ate yesterday, they would be better than _The Force Awakens_. Probably the worst film I've ever seen, both in the context of the franchise and as a film in its own right. Rather impressive!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Wish I paid £10 to you and not my local cinema @_@

Comment: @user17 True, but knowledge questions are not the same as math questions. "What color is the sky" and "Is the sky blue" are not the same question. But it would still be redundant to have both.

Comment: @user1717828 Well, the questions `2 + 2 + 2` and `3 x 2` are pretty much the same, actually.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Yes

For example, [the wedding of Anakin and Padme](http://Wedding_of_Anakin_Skywalker_and_Padm%C3%A9_Amidala).

Additionally, from *[Attack of the Clones](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html)*:

> CLIEGG
>                   (continuing)
>               Cliegg Lars. Shmi is my wife...
>               Come on inside. We have a lot to
>               talk about.

And *[The Force Awakens](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html)*:

> She sees Han and is stunned. A silent beat, husband and
>             wife reunited for the first time in years. In the smoke and
>             embers, no one says a word.

[Here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage) are some other canon marriages.

Answer (score 69):

Anakin and Padme were married. Their wedding occurred in Episode II:

[image]

[Cliegg Lars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cliegg_Lars) took Anakin's mother Shmi as his wife after he freed her from slavery (in Episode II):

> Shmi is my wife...Come on inside. We have a lot to talk about.

Bail Organa mentioned his wife when he took Leia as a child in Episode III:

> My wife and I will take the girl. We've always talked of adopting a baby girl. She will be loved with us.

From @Richard's answer to [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113231/31936), Han and Leia were married according to the official novelization:

> Left alone again, husband and wife also embraced. Han murmured over
>   her shoulder, “I saw him. He was here.”

I can't find a direct confirmation that Luke's adoptive parents Owen and Beru were married, but the [archived profile on Owen Lars from starwars.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20140409154334/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/characters/owenlars/) mentions that

> Owen dated Beru Whitesun when he was a young man. The two soon married, and worked hard together to eke out a living in the deserts of Tatooine.

Comment: @RogueJedi and Null: Shmi Skywalker also eventually married, although that marriage happened off-screen.

Comment: This is funny to watch. It's like an arms race, but with facts.

Answer (score 18):

As both answers have already stated Anakin and Padme were married at the end of episode II

Also in ROTS Anakin says

> I don't care if they know we're married.

Comment: If other answers have stated this, why did you feel the need to restate it?

Comment: Other answers have stated it but neither used the Quote. This answer was simply meant to compliment the others and improve on that point in particular.

Comment: I don't really think the quote is necessary. Anyone who didn't get up and leave during AotC would know that Padme and Anakin were married.

Comment: If that was so the OP wouldn't have asked the Question

Comment: A comment on another answer mentioning the quote would probably have been sufficient.

Comment: And yet I have Five up votes so...

Comment: That simply makes the reaction to this answer confusing. Both answers show *the actual ceremony*. I'm not sure what this one quote, as a standalone answer, adds to anything.

Comment: Guys, if you don't like the answer, downvote and move on.

Comment: @user1717828: How does drive-by downvoting without explanation help anybody? If you don't like the answer, downvote _and explain why_ so that the author has a chance to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Also, let us not forget in Star Wars: A New Hope, Luke's uncle and aunt could most likely have been married before being murdered.

This excerpt is taking from Wikipedia:

> Owen tells Anakin they are stepbrothers. Owen later marries Beru Whitesun. As a Jedi Knight, Anakin secretly marries Padmé Amidala, who gives birth to twins, Luke and Leia. Star Wars: Episode III – Revenge of the Sith reveals that Luke's caregivers on Tatooine, Beru and Owen Lars, are his step-aunt and uncle.

Link can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skywalker_family):